# UWP customise AcrylicBrush TintColour with ColorPicker

Tags: c#

I need to try to alter a AcrylicBrush TintColour and Opacity settings using a ColorPicker.

The AcrylicBrush seems to consist of more arguments than the SolidColorBrush that i have been dealing with currently.

The syntax im using currently that doesnt seem to work is the following:

```
public AcrylicBrush BGColourBrush;

private void BackgroundColourPicker_ColorChanged(ColorPicker sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            BGColourBrush.TintColor = new AcrylicBrush(MenuColourPicker.Color);
            MainPage.NavViewVariable.Background = BGColourBrush;    
        }
```

The syntax for this is wrong and throws an error:

> 'AcrylicBrush' does not contain a constructor that takes one argument

Is there a way to do the following:

- Assign the MenuColourPicker.Color to the TintColor property of the AcrylicBrush?
- Read the "Alpha" values from the ColorPicker and assign them to
  AcrylicBrush Opacity (if not, i will create a seperate slider for this later)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace:

```
 BGColourBrush.TintColor = new AcrylicBrush(MenuColourPicker.Color);
```

With

```
BGColourBrush = new AcrylicBrush { TintColor = MenuColourPicker.Color, Opacity = MenuColourPicker.Color.A };
```

Comment: Happy to help :)